# C++ Search Windows Registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry, key

I'm trying to search the registry for keys in a particular group(Local-> Windows -> Uninstall) so I can eventually uninstall these applications programatically. I am having problems getting the key name so I can open it.  Here is what I have tried:

```
void Uninstall::uninstallProgram(string appName)
{
    HKEY currentKey;
    TCHAR name[1024];
    DWORD dwSize = 1024, dwIdx = 0;
    FILETIME fTime;
    long result;

    result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, POLICY_KEY, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_SET_VALUE, &currentKey);

    if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "Error opening Installation Registry, verify that this location exists under: " << POLICY_KEY << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * The installation path has been verified, now need to start looking for the correct program to uninstall
         */

        for(int index = 0; result == ERROR_SUCCESS; index++)
        {
            if (RegEnumKeyEx(currentKey, 0, name, &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, &fTime))
            {
                cout << string() << name << endl;
//              if (name == appName)
//              {
//                  system(execute the uninstall string)
//              }
            }
        }


    }
```

How can I retrieve the current key name to compare it against the name of the application that I am trying to uninstall?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you just forgot to request KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS access right. Also it's possible that I do not understand exactly what are you trying to do but AFAIK Uninstall folder have different location.

```
HKEY currentKey;
TCHAR name[1024];
DWORD dwSize = 1024, dwIdx = 0;
long result;
result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall" ), 0, KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS | KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_SET_VALUE, &currentKey);

if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
  // fail
}
else
{
  DWORD index = 0;
  while ( ERROR_SUCCESS == RegEnumKeyEx(currentKey, index, name, &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) ) {
    // name buffer is already contains key name here
    // ...
    dwSize = 1024; // restore dwSize after is is set to key's length by RegEnumKeyEx
    ++index; // increment subkey index
  } 
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. It was interesting to research this :) I've never worked with registry before.

Comment: BTW There is an example for keys removing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724235%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Searching through my registry shows that in order to found all entries to uninstall you should check few locations:
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Comment: It's require to google about that but it seems that first one is for applications that is installed just for current users, second one - apps for all users and third one is for handling 32-64 compatibility (I have 64-bit Windows 7). Also elevation will be required for accessing HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (at least for removing keys) I think.

Answer (score 3):

below is a working compiled code to recursively search through registry for a value name , i know lotta people are looking for it and i think there is no working code around to do this .

compiled using MinGW

```
// Say Shaloom to Ammar Hourani who did code troubleshooting and compiled this
// QueryKey - Enumerates the subkeys of key and its associated values.
//     hKey - Key whose subkeys and values are to be enumerated.

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>



#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
#define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383


void QueryKey(char * originalpath , char * searchvalue) 
{ 

    HKEY hKey;
    if( RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER,TEXT(originalpath),0,KEY_READ,&hKey)     == ERROR_SUCCESS)
       {
           TCHAR    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
            DWORD    cbName;                   // size of name string 
            TCHAR    achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");  // buffer for class name 
            DWORD    cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string 
            DWORD    cSubKeys=0;               // number of subkeys 
            DWORD    cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size 
            DWORD    cchMaxClass;              // longest class string 
            DWORD    cValues;              // number of values for key 
            DWORD    cchMaxValue;          // longest value name 
            DWORD    cbMaxValueData;       // longest value data 
            DWORD    cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor 
            FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;      // last write time 

            DWORD i, retCode; 

            CHAR  achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME]; 

            DWORD cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME; 
            char * dndr = new char[MAX_VALUE_NAME]();


            // Get the class name and the value count. 
            retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(
                hKey,                    // key handle 
                achClass,                // buffer for class name 
                &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
                NULL,                    // reserved 
                &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
                &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
                &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
                &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
                &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
                &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
                &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
                &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 

            // Enumerate the subkeys, until RegEnumKeyEx fails.
        if (cSubKeys)
        {


            for (i=0; i<cSubKeys; i++) 
            { 
                cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
                retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey,     i,achKey,&cbName,NULL,NULL,NULL,&ftLastWriteTime); 
                if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
                {
                    strcpy(dndr,originalpath);

                    strcat(dndr,"\\");
                    strcat(dndr,achKey);

                    QueryKey(dndr,searchvalue);

                }
            }
        } 

        // Enumerate the key values. 

        if (cValues) 
        {


            for (i=0, retCode=ERROR_SUCCESS; i<cValues; i++) 
            { 
                cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME; 
                //achValue[0] = '\0'; 
                memset(achValue, 0, sizeof(achValue));
                retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i, 
                achValue, 
                &cchValue, 
                NULL, 
                NULL,
                NULL,
                NULL);

            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
            {
                if (!strncmp(achValue,searchvalue,strlen(searchvalue))) cout << "\n One Hit at: " << originalpath << endl;

            } 
        }
    }
}
RegCloseKey(hKey);
}


int __cdecl _tmain(void)
{
   QueryKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Office","MTTA");
   cin.get();
   return 1;

}
```

Comment: +1 With changes: "#include <iostream>"  and adding "using namespace std;" this is a very helpful demo. Shaloom.

Answer (score 0):

The raw api for registry access is pretty ugly - its standard practice to use one of the many available wrapper classes that make this a whole less painful.  There are literally dozens of these on codeproject.

Comment: I purposely did it with the raw api so I could learn how it worked, worst case, I will fall back to one of these wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the current index to get the name, and then check for `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS`:

```
bool quit = false;

for(int index = 0; !quit; index++)
{
    LSTATUS Return = RegEnumKeyEx(currentKey, index, name, &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, &fTime);
    if(Return == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        quit = true;
    }
    else if(Return == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << string() << name << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        quit = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run it like this, my 'Return' value is always coming back as 5 which is access denied even though I am running eclipse as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your index variable in your RegEnumKeyEx call. You are always passing in 0 for the dwIndex parameter. Stop enumerating when it returns ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS.